# Keyboard layout changes on change of focus at KDE

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, kde, keyboard-layout

I have a Debian 9.5 (stable) with KDE and i've binded three commands to three **different** global shortcuts with System Settings -> Shortuts

```
setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout us 
setxkbmap -model abnt2 -layout br -variant abnt2
setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout us -variant intl
```

But these layouts change to the primary layout when i change the focus.

I also tried to bind the shortcuts using the System Settings -> Inputs Devices with the global switching policy, but that does'not work too.

This is the result from `setxkbmap -query`:

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc101
layout:     br,us,us
variant:    ,intl,
```